# Using ajax to pass text to a db

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to take simple text from a form, pass it to my controller via ajax, and have that send to the data base.

View

```
 <form method="POST">
   Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
   Question: <input type="text" name="qText" id="qText">
  <input id="rate" type="submit">
 </form>

 <script type = "text/javascript">

 $(function(){
   $("#rate").click(function(){
     dataString = $("#email").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/trial/insert_into_db",
            data: dataString,

                       });
               });
     });

  </script>
```

The controller code and the model code work fine. I am almost sure that it is the ajax code that is not working.

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The browser's debug console will let you examine the network requests made by your webpage -- this will help you determine if any problems are client-side or server-side.

Comment: if you are using Internet Explorer, F12 developer tools, network, start capturing should show more information about the request.            I think the issue is with your url. the "insert_into_db" method should be public and add necessary attributes. sorry I don't have idea about php.

Comment: What returns the base_url() function ? maybe you didnt add a slash at the end..? try adding slash /index.php/trial/insert_into_db

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick replies guys. I am using google chrome @jasen  . Do I go to console, then debug at the bottom?

Comment: the baseurl is set in my config file (using code igniter). It has a / at the end of, which is why I dont add the slash @daguru

Comment: F12 opens the debug console. There's a network tab to monitor requests and the console that will display debug output and script errors.

Comment: When using the Network screen it is sometimes helpful to enable "Preserve Log upon Navigation" -- there's a small round button at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I am like almost positive is is the url part because it doesnt run any of the function in my controller

Comment: When you click the button what request is generated? Is it the URL that you expect?

Comment: No it doesnt. I intentionally put a view that displays a '1' to check if its working. if I use an action on the form to call the same function in the controller, it works fine @jasen

Answer (score 0):

One thing missing from your posted code is disabling the default form submission. There still could be other issues.

You don't specify an action so by default the action is the same url as the page.

```
<form method="POST">
```

You are doing AJAX but you have not disabled the default behavior with `return false` or `event.preventDefault`

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // or
    return false;
});
```

I prefer `preventDefault()` but the point is you need to prevent the default browser behavior.

**Edit**: This is how I would submit the form with AJAX.

If you had more than one form button to consider then

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#rate").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

But it's (marginally) easier to do it with one handler. I'd also stick the action on the form so the form still submits to the correct url if the javascript failed.

```
<form id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/trial/insert_into_db" method="post">
```

Instead of handling the button click handle the form submission

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type = "post",
        url = $(this).attr("action"),
        data = formData
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        // do something with the response
    });
});
```

Comment: Replace the button click handler with the form submission handler would be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: This works, but it is not using the ajax. It is just using the action on the form. Any idea why it isnt using the ajax at all?

Comment: If you placed the `insert_into_db` url into the form action `$(this).attr("action")` takes the form action and will POST to the very same url. What leads you to believe ajax isn't used at all?

Comment: Maybe ajax is being used, but not in the way we intended. We dont want the url to change at all. We want it to be the same as it were before ajax was clicked. We dont want it to be baseurl.com/index.php/trial/insert_into_db @jasen